# Personalizar botón (toggle) addLayersControl

Tags: javascript, html, css, r, leaflet

Buen día, actualmente tengo un mapa Leaflet con diferentes capas en una aplicación Shiny. Tengo el control de capas configurado en modo colapsado, pero me piden que el botón sea más llamativo para los usuarios. Mi pregunta es ¿hay alguna forma de personalizar el botón de control de capas cuando está colapsado?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi código es este:

````
leaflet() %>% 
            addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap.Mapnik) %>%
            setView( -102, 23, zoom = 5) %>%
            clearControls() %>%
            clearShapes() %>%
            addPolygons(data = shp_00ent, group = '---', fillColor =~palet(`% no_a_e`),
                        color = '#212529', weight = 0.3, smoothFactor = 0.5, fillOpacity = 0.5, opacity = 1.0,
                        highlightOptions = highlightOptions(color = 'red',weight = 2,bringToFront = TRUE),
                        label = labels_ent,
                        labelOptions = labelOptions(style = list('font-weight' = 'normal', padding = '3px 8px'),textsize = '15px',direction = 'auto'),
                        popup = ~paste('<center>',
                                       '<FONT SIZE=4>','<b>',`NOMGEO`,'</b>','</font>','<br/>',
                                       '<b>','---','</b>','<br/>',
                                       '<FONT SIZE=6>','<b>',`---`,'%','</b>','</font>','<br/>',
                                       '<b>',`---`,'NNA','</b>',
                                       '</center>') ) %>%
            addPolygons(data = shp_00ent, group = '---', fillColor =~palet(`% h_l_i_TI`),
                        color = '#212529', weight = 0.3, smoothFactor = 0.5,
                        fillOpacity = 0.5, opacity = 1.0,
                        highlightOptions = highlightOptions(color = 'red',weight = 2,bringToFront = TRUE),
                        label = labels_ent,
                        labelOptions = labelOptions(style = list('font-weight' = 'normal', padding = '3px 8px'),textsize = '15px',direction = 'auto'),
                        popup = ~paste('<center>',
                                       '<FONT SIZE=4>','<b>',`NOMGEO`,'</b>','</font>','<br/>',
                                       '<b>','---','</b>','<br/>',
                                       '<FONT SIZE=6>','<b>',`---`,'%','</b>','</font>','<br/>',
                                       '<b>',`---`,'NNA','</b>',
                                       '</center>') ) %>% 
            addPolygons(data = shp_00ent, group = '---', fillColor =~palet(`% s_p_j_TI`),
                        color = '#212529', weight = 0.3, smoothFactor = 0.5,
                        fillOpacity = 0.5, opacity = 1.0,
                        highlightOptions = highlightOptions(color = 'red',weight = 2,bringToFront = TRUE),
                        label = labels_ent,
                        labelOptions = labelOptions(style = list('font-weight' = 'normal', padding = '3px 8px'),textsize = '15px',direction = 'auto'),
                        popup = ~paste('<center>',
                                       '<FONT SIZE=4>','<b>',`NOMGEO`,'</b>','</font>','<br/>',
                                       '<b>','---','</b>','<br/>',
                                       '<FONT SIZE=6>','<b>',`---`,'%','</b>','</font>','<br/>',
                                       '<b>',`---`,'NNA','</b>',
                                       '</center>') ) %>% 
            addPolygons(data = shp_00ent, group = '---', fillColor =~palet(`% E_j_p_TI`),
                        color = '#212529', weight = 0.3, smoothFactor = 0.5,
                        fillOpacity = 0.5, opacity = 1.0,
                        highlightOptions = highlightOptions(color = 'red',weight = 2,bringToFront = TRUE),
                        label = labels_ent,
                        labelOptions = labelOptions(style = list('font-weight' = 'normal', padding = '3px 8px'),textsize = '15px',direction = 'auto'),
                        popup = ~paste('<center>',
                                       '<FONT SIZE=4>','<b>',`NOMGEO`,'</b>','</font>','<br/>',
                                       '<b>','---','</b>','<br/>',
                                       '<FONT SIZE=6>','<b>',`---`,'%','</b>','</font>','<br/>',
                                       '<b>',`---`,'NNA','</b>',
                                       '</center>') )%>% 
            addLayersControl( baseGroups = baseGroups_vars,  options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = TRUE)  ) ```
````